# toggleClass not reacting

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have a toggle class function that i cant seem to get to work:

```
    $(function () {
        $(".choices").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        })
    });
```

CSS:

```
.choices {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #696868;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #696868;
    box-shadow: inset 0 8px 8px -8px #696868;
    align-content:center;
}
.choices.active {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I've done it before with the exact same properties. I dont know if its because the div contains an svg inside. Tried removing the SVG, but no luck at all.

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dh8kqd6k/embedded/result/

Comment: In your jsfiddle you forgot to include jQuery. See http://jsbin.com/ximezajipe/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7owxwhLx/ works perfectly. In your active class is not different from the default style you get from choices class

Comment: How is active class CSS different from CSS already there for choices class selector? Won't you need to assign some property value for box-shadow for active class?

Comment: Well, it doesnt toggle any of the other active classes that i made including "choices". i can see it in the browser that it does nothing. The shadow are suppoesed to be nothing. I did include jquery

Comment: Okay, well i got it to work. Or.. well, it always worked, however it only activates when i click the border of "choices", tried display: inline-block / block.. but nothing changes, it still only reacts when i click on the border.